# Not able to get more than 4000 character in clob input parameter

Tags: clob

I am trying to use clob data type as input parameter in stored procedure oracle 12c, When  data more than 4000+ character comes  from application it accept only first 4000 character. and rest of the character get ignored. 
So I just wanted to know could we pass 4000+ character as clob input parameter?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: According to this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits001.htm#i287903 is should be much higher. 4000 bytes "smells" like a varchar?